# Term for two notes played together only a half step apart

Tags: terminology, intervals

What is the term for two notes played on a piano that are only a half step apart, such as a C and a C# being played together?

Comment: I didn’t vote to close at first, but the variety of the answers should show that the question needs clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It's just called a half step, or a minor second. (Technically, a minor second would be C and Db.) More generally, it could be called a *dissonance*. Also generally it could be called a *chord*, though more often than not chords are defined as having three notes rather than two — some people call it a "simultaneity" for clarity.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *"chord"*.  I usually think that chords need at least three notes.  I would call it an interval.  And a minor second interval.  (I realize that an *"open fifth chord"* is the same as a perfect fifth interval.)

Answer (score 3):

To sum up what others have already said, C and C# are not notes you're likely to see together. If anything, you're much more likely (and even that is not particularly often) to see C and Db. Which is the interval of a [minor second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitone#Minor_second).

Other examples of minor seconds are E and F, or F# and G, or A and Bb, or C# and D, and so on. B# and C# (which is even less common than C and Db) would also make for a minor second.

C and C# would be called an [augmented unison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_unison), but as noted, it's rare.

Saying "semitone", "half tone" or "half step" is also correct.

Comment: "Lionel [rejected premiering the Walton Viola concerto because he] couldn't imagine that a chord containing [both] C sharp and C natural could possibly sound well." - Lionel Tertis' wife Lilian.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, this is called a minor second. Rarely it's notated as an augmented unison or doubly diminished third. The label depends on the use.

Comment: I think it could even more rarely be a doubly diminished second, e.g. B# to Cb.

Comment: @supercat, while I *love* your comment, I’d also love to see you find one in a real piece…!

Comment: @BobBroadley: Such a thing could plausibly occur in a transition from C# minor to Gb major.  I think an editor would probably strongly encourage using F# major instead of Gb, but there could be reasons for favoring the six-flats key signature.

Answer (score 1):

C and C♯ played together doesn't have a specific name - as both notes are Cs.

Change that C♯ to a D♭, though, and there is an interval name available. Any C>D is a 2nd, so here it will become *minor 2nd*

Another very slight possibility is that the upper note may be an E of some sort, and E♭♭♭ would fit the bill enharmonically. In that remote case, the interval C>E♭♭♭ would be called double diminished. A rare beast indeed!

One could also take the C♮ note to actually be (enharmonically) B♯, with similar implications. But the two notes played together will 99% of the time be written C and D♭.

But, as you say, *half-step* will suffice, most will understand that it's a semitone between them.

Comment: What about C and Bx? (Really ugly. But impossible?)

Comment: @Divizna - I got fed up by the end, but certainly, technically, C and Bx would be yet another (weird) interval. Probably named ... haven't a clue, as intervals are calculated from the lower note - and which would that be..? Theory gone mad!

Comment: Doubly diminished second? It would be a very wtf interval anyway.

Comment: C to C♯ is called an augmented unison; it's just that in 12-TET it's enharmonically equivalent to the minor second.

Answer (score 1):

If it's C and C♯ we can label it as an Augmented Unison.  If C and D♭, a Minor 2nd.   Just two notes aren't enough for a chord name, though C and D♭ could be part of D♭maj7.  Quite likely it's not harmonic at all,just a percussive effect.